# How to create a generalised formula from a set of formula (number stairs investigation)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on an investigation, and I am unsure of how to proceed with making a final generalised formula from these formulae. The formulae have variables p (which is the length of the number stair), g, which is the size of the grid, and also n, which is the number in the bottom left of the number staircase. 
I am working on a formula to use three variables to determine the sum of all numbers inside the number staircase at any given size. I am pretty much stumped on how to go on from this point. This is what I've done so far:
$g + 3n + 1$ when p = 2
$4g + 6n + 6$ when p = 3
$10g + 10n + 10$ when p = 4

This is the investigation - albeit a simplified version: http://www.transum.org/Software/Investigations/numberstairs.asp

I have found a formula off the internet that works, but I don't know how to get to it myself. $(p(p+1)/2)n + (g+1)/6 (p-1) (p+1) ( p )$

Could someone please explain how to get from my formulae or any way to get from the investigation to the extended formula please?

Thank you :)

Comment: Try to calculate the sum of just one 'step' of the stair at a time and then sum all this values together.

Comment: It still is quite confusing(but less so as a single step) to me but I shall try it thanks:)

Comment: Take the example one a $10 \times 10$ grid and a 3 step ladder. Take a any starting bottom value for the stair and call it $n$. The sum of the first step is $$ \underbrace{n}_\text{bloc number 1} + \underbrace{n+1}_\text{block number 2} + \underbrace{n+2}_\text{block number 3} = 3 n + (1+2) = 3n + 3$$

Comment: ah i see now, but I need to create an equation that takes into account the amount of steps on its own, and then calculates the total value of the whole staircase in one go - so the width of the steps constantly changes, and my equations work with the sum of the whole thing but not just one step - but maybe i can find one for p length of stair..hmm maybe that will work

Comment: If you're trying to calculate the sum of the first line of a stair of size p you would still follow the same principal: $$ n + (n+1) + (n+2) + ... (n + (p-1) ) = np + (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + p)$$

Comment: thanks ill try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first figure out how to sum $p$ blocks on the same line starting at block of value $n$ we note this sum a $S_n(p)$

\begin{align*}
 S_n(p) &= n + (n+1) + ... + \big(n + (p-1)\big)\\
&= pn + (1+2+...+ p-1) \\
&= pn + \frac{(p-1)p}{2} \\
\end{align*}

If you take a $p$-stair with starting value $n$ in a $g\times g$ grid then the sum on the first row is equal to $S_n(p)$ the second step of the stair is also the sum of consecutive blocs i.e. p-1 consecutive blocks starting at the value just above $n$ in the table. The second step starts at the block $n+g$ and we sum on p-1 blocks. This implies that the sum on all the blocks on the second step is equal to $S_{n+g}(p-1)$ according to our definition

The of the entire tree will be given by

$$ \underbrace{S_n(p)}_\text{step 1} + \underbrace{S_{n+g}(p-1)}_\text{step 2} + \underbrace{S_{n+2g}(p-2)}_\text{step 3} + ... + \underbrace{S_{n + (p-1)g}(1)}_\text{last step}$$

Comment: to be honest, i did not really understand that sadly:( do you think you could explain this long formula...(p(p+1)/2)n+(g+1)/6(p−1)(p+1)(p)

Comment: What did you specifically not understand ?

Comment: My mistake I assumed you would know the following result. The sum of the first $n$ naturals is given by $$ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ for example for $n = 5$ we have  $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = (5 \cdot 6) / 2 = 15$ in this case $n = p-1$ and the formula become $$\frac{(p-1)(p - 1 + 1)}{2} = \frac{(p-1)p}{2}$$

Comment: Oh ok I see that now... awesime thanks